# Вывод данных из mysql за определенный период

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица `static` в ней поля `id(int(10))`, `date(date)`, `datachange(timestamp)`, `name(text)`, и др.

Через `GET` передаются данные в php

- `data_from` - начальная дата
- `date_to` - конечная дата

```php
$date_from = $_GET['data_from'];
$date_to = $_GET['date_to'];
```

Данные передаются в формате год-месяц-день. То есть на выходе имеем

> $date_from = '2017-09-28';
>
> $date_to = '2017-10-17';

Теперь необходимо получить данные только за этот период дат, которые получили раннее. Но при выполнение запроса:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `static` where `date` >= '$date_from' AND `date` <= '$date_to'  ORDER BY `date`";
```

Выдаются еще данные которые меньше начальной даты. То есть я еще получаю данные и за август, и за начало сентября. С конечной датой проблем не возникает.

Как получить получить данные только за отведенный период?

То есть например с `2017-09-28` по `2017-10-17`.

Comment: `$date_from = $_GET['data_from'];` - здесь нет опечатки? Может `$date_from = $_GET['datЕ_from']`? Что показывает вывод `var_dump($strSQL)`?

Comment: Прочитай, пожалуйста, про [between](http://tigor.com.ua/blog/2008/08/23/date_comparison_by_between_operator_of_mysql/)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov спасибо. Я три дня потратил на поиск этой ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте оператор mysql [BETWEEN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

Comment: Использовал до этого и битвен. Результат был нулевой. Но после исправление опечатки в коде заработали оба варианта. Спасибо